# Java regex get unmatched portion

Tags: java, regex

I am matching a regex of the form

```
abc.*def.*pqr.*xyz
```

Now the string `abc123def456pqr789xyz` will match the pattern.
I want to find the strings 123, 456, 789 with the matcher.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the regex to `abc(.*)def(.*)pqr(.*)xyz` and the parentheses will be automatically bound to

- the variables `$1` through `$3` if
  you use [String.replaceAll()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or
- [Matcher.group(n)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) if you use
  [Matcher.find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

See the documentation of the [Pattern class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), especially [Groups and Capturing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg), for more info.

**Sample Code:**

```
final String needle = "abc(.*)def(.*)pqr(.*)xyz";
final String hayStack = "abcXdefYpqrZxyz";

// Use $ variables in String.replaceAll()
System.out.println(hayStack.replaceAll(needle, "_$1_$2_$3_"));
// Output: _X_Y_Z_


// Use Matcher groups:
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(needle).matcher(hayStack);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(
        "A: " + matcher.group(1) +
        ", B: " + matcher.group(2) +
        ", C: " + matcher.group(3)
    );
}
// Output: A: X, B: Y, C: Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that might do what you need.

```
abc(\\d*)def(\\d*)pqr(\\d*)xyz
```

But, we should have more examples of input strings, and what should be matched.